# Find the complex Fourier series

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Find the complex Fourier series representation of the function

$$
f(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,\quad\text{if}\quad 0 < t < 2 \\ 
0,\quad\text{if}\quad 2 < t < 4
\end{cases}
$$
with the period 4.

Comment: Where are you having problems? Apart from the fact that you didn't specify the period, this is a pretty straightforward integration.

Comment: ... or table-checking.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients are

$$c_{n} = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2}e^{- i\frac{\pi n x}{2}}dx = \frac{i}{2 \pi n}(e^{- i\pi n}-1),$$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}.$

For $n = 0:$

$$c_{0} = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2}dx \Rightarrow c_0 = \frac{1}{2}.$$

For $n$ odd:

$$c_{n} = \frac{i}{2 \pi n}(e^{- i\pi n}-1)= -\frac{i}{\pi n}.$$

For $n$ even, and $n >0$:

$$c_{n} = \frac{i}{2 \pi n}(e^{- i\pi n}-1)= 0.$$

Thus,
$$f(x) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{\frac{i\pi n x}{2}}.$$